# Computation of a certain integral involving cyclotomics

Tags: contour-integration, cyclotomic-polynomials

How would one compute $\frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_{|z| = \frac{1}{2}} \frac{\Phi_{n}(z)}{z^{k + 1}} dz$ in terms of k and n. If this is not possible, how would someone find a good approximation for this.

Edit:
I have worked on this and have found a simplification:
$\frac{1}{2\pi i }\oint_{|z| = \frac{1}{2}} \frac{\Phi_{n}(z)}{z^{k + 1}} dz = \frac{\Phi_n^{(k)}(0)}{k!} = \int_0^1 \Phi_{n}(e(\alpha))e(n\alpha) d\alpha$ 
by the orthogonality relation $\int_0^1e(nx) dx = 1$ if $n = 0$ and equals $0$ otherwise.

($\Phi_{n}(x)$ is the nth cyclotomic polynomial)

Comment: See generalized Cauchy formula.

Comment: I went backwards from the nth derivative to this form.

Comment: So, do you want to find the $n$th derivative of $\frac{\Phi_k(0)}{k!}$?

Comment: Yes, it is the kth coefficient of the nth cyclotomic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

I, for one would use t[he explicit formula in terms of the Möbius function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial), followed by the Residue theorem.

Comment: How would I deal with the mobius function and the product easily?

Comment: @MayankPandey What exactly do you want to do to them?

Comment: I want to be able to use this to find the kth coefficient of the nth cyclotomic polynomial. The integral is this by the Cauchy-Integral Formula.

Comment: You want a formula for the coefficients of cyclotomic polynomials?  That sounds quite optimistic!